# Make an array (1, x, x^2) based on x in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, polynomials

Let's suppose that I have dataframe `df` similar like:

```
c0     c1  
10     2        
8      2         
4      1
```

How can I make an `np.array` for each element of this datafrmae so that I have for each element array (1, x, x^2)?

For example for col1, first element (0) should get the array `[1, 2, 4]`, for c0, for the fisrt elemend (10), get `[1,10,100]` etc.

The new np.array should then have the dimensions `(2 x 3 x 3)`, 2 for two columns, 3 for 3 rows and 3 for 3 values `[1,x,x^2]`?

I tried:

```
df.loc[:,i].apply(lambda x: np.power(x,np.arange(3)))
```

But I could not get the wanted form of np.array (dimensions: 2 x 3 x 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy approach would be to broadcast to a 3D array:

```
out = df.to_numpy()[...,None]**[0,1,2]
```

Output:

```
array([[[  1,  10, 100],
        [  1,   2,   4]],

       [[  1,   8,  64],
        [  1,   2,   4]],

       [[  1,   4,  16],
        [  1,   1,   1]]])
```

If you want a `(2, 3, 3)` shape, swap the axes:

```
out = (df.to_numpy()[...,None]**[0,1,2]).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

output:

```
array([[[  1,  10, 100],
        [  1,   8,  64],
        [  1,   4,  16]],

       [[  1,   2,   4],
        [  1,   2,   4],
        [  1,   1,   1]]])
```

Comment: Yeap, this was a clever way how to do it! Thanks!